# Create oembed previews for my selfhosted WP?

Tags: wordpress, self-hosting, oembed

I have a simple WP instance running on a vhost system. I always wondered why there is no preview when I share a link of my articles e.g. at facebook. I read that WP has oEmbed support, so I'm confused, because there is no line at the final resulting HTML source ...
More confused, because it seems that you can just [get your previews](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oembed-provider-api/) of you join the wordpress.com network?

In short: How can I enable/add oEmbed support to my own local blog and offer previews of my posts?

P.S. No, this is not about embeding other platforms content (yt, flickr, ...) and get html previews on videos, images, ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A self-hosted oEmbed provider: A simple *Hello World* demo

Here's a very simple demo of a **self hosted oembed provider** (site A) that implements the *json* spec on [oembed.com](http://oembed.com/) for **rich** *type* responses. Other available types are *link*, *photo* and *video*.

**Site A:**

This site is a self-hosted **oembed provider** that supports the *json* format and only implements the *required* oembed specs and skips the *optional* parameters.

We also implement `404` for urls not found and `501` for formats not available.

The key functions used here, are `url_to_postid()`, `status_header()`, `get_post()` and `wp_send_json()`.

```
/**
 * Demo: A simple self-hosted oEmbed provider.
 */

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'simple_oembed_provider_so27693829' ) 

function simple_oembed_provider_so27693829()
{
    // Catch the user input:
    $input = filter_input_array( INPUT_GET, array(
        'simple-oembed'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
         'url'       => FILTER_SANITIZE_URL,
         'format'    => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
         'maxwidth'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
         'maxheight' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
        )
    );

    // Our oembed service is activated:
    if( 1 == $input['simple-oembed'] )
    {
        //--------------
        // We only support json format:
        //--------------
        if( 'json' != $input['format'] ) 
        {
            status_header( 501 ); 
            nocache_headers();
            exit();

        $pid = url_to_postid( $input['url'] );

        //--------------
        // The url doesn't exists:
        //--------------
        if( 0 == $pid ) 
        {
            status_header( 404 );     
            nocache_headers();
            exit();
        }

        //--------------
        // json output:
        //--------------
        else
        {
            $post = get_post( $pid );
            $data = array(
                'version' => '1.0',
                'type'    => 'rich',
                'width'   => empty( $input['maxwidth'] ) ? 600 : min( 600, $input['maxwidth'] ),
                'height'  => empty( $input['maxheight'] ) ? 400 : min( 400, $input['maxheight'] ), 
                'html'    => sprintf(
                   '<div class="simple-oembed"><h2><a href="%s">%s</a></h2><p>%s</p></div>',
                    get_permalink( $pid ),
                    apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title ),    
                    'Check out this great post!'
                )
            );
            wp_send_json( $data );
        }
    }
}
```

**Site B:**

To test the oembed service provided by Site A, we must register it via:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_our_oembed_provider_so27693829' );

function add_our_oembed_provider_so27693829()
{
    wp_oembed_add_provider( 
        $format   = 'http://site-a.tld/*', 
        $provider = 'http://site-a.tld/?simple-oembed=1&' 
    );
}
```

on site B.

Then when we add a `site-a.tld` link in the editor we get:

**Before saving:**

[image: Hello world link]

**After saving:**

[image: Hello World oembedded]

Here `site-b.tld` will send the following GET request to `site-a.tld`:

```
http://site-a.tld/?simple-oembed=1
&format=json
&maxwidth=625
&maxheight=938
&url=http://site-a.tld/hello-world/
```

which gives the following 200 status response:

```
{
    "version":"1.0",
    "type":"rich",
    "width":600,
    "height":400,
    "html":"<div class=\"simple-oembed\"><h2><a href=\"http:\/\/site-a.tld\/hello-world\/\">Hello World from Site A<\/a><\/h2><p>Check out this great post!<\/p><\/div>"
}
```

ps: I've not mentioned the auto oEmbed discovery.

**Helpful resources:**

- [The oEmbed specs](http://oembed.com).
- [The oEmbed Provider plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oembed-provider/) (I'm not related to this one, but it helped me while writing this answer.)
- If you want to know how to use the WordPress JSON REST API plugin by Ryan McCue, with the oembed provider, you might want to check out [this](https://spinpress.com/wordpress-oembed-provider-plugin/) blog post and [this](https://timnash.co.uk/becoming-oembed-provider/) one (both great).

Comment: Thanks for your great detailed answer :) To my suprise, the mentioned The oEmbed Provider plugin wasn't listed at my WP. I installed it and now everything is fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mam, you're welcome, I'm glad to hear you found some use for the answer ;-)

Comment: Just one note: I figured out, that I was looking for #OpenGraph plugin instead. While OpenEmbed is pretty similar, it's usually just allowed for a smal amount of major sites due to cross site scripting problems. OG is pretty limited but so usually allows :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add the OG meta tags to your themes header.php in the  section before wp_head():

I copied this from my themes header.php so you may have to change it to your needs.

Edit: you can see my themes header.php online at github: https://github.com/service4me/sandbox-wordpress-theme/blob/master/header.php

OG Title:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title( '');?> - <?php echo wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ?>" />
```

OG Type:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>article<?php } else { ?>Website<?php } ?>" />
```

OG URL:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

OG Image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if ( is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() ) { 

      $ogImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),’large’, true);

      echo $ogImageUrl[0];

    } else {

      echo bloginfo('template_directory'), '/img/logo.png';

    } ?>" />
```

OG Description:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php if ( is_front_page() ) {

      bloginfo('description');

    } else {

      if ( is_single() ) {

        echo htmlspecialchars( get_the_excerpt() );

      } else {

        wp_title( '');

      }

    } ?>" />
```

OG Locale:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_AT" />
```

Comment: Thanks also for your answer. Also for OG there are existing ready to use plugins that offer what you coded manually ;-)

Comment: there are plugins for everything but they may have bugs and security holes so i prefer to code myself when i am able to. then i know what exactly happens